# How to convert the "_" (underscore) in a string to "-" (hyphen) inside Ansible Jinja template?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am looking for a way to convert "example_test_password" to "test-password" inside Jinja2 templates. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Muhammed Roshan

Answer (score 23):

Did you try this:

```
{{ "example_test_password"|replace("example_", "")|replace("_", "-") }}
```

For more help visit jinja2 [doc](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#replace)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in that answer too. The question says also replacing some text, so the solution should be different IMHO

Comment: @imjoseangel he just want to remove the example_ from the text and convert the underscore to -.

Comment: You can use `regex_replace` for that. Didn't test locally but is what I would prefer -> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html